# Why am I getting 'E0000022' on Okta OAuth2.0 /api/v1/authorize endpoint?

Tags: python, okta, okta-api

I am trying to authenticate a user through OKTA API.

I am following these steps:

- make post request to `/api/v1/authn` providing user and password
- given this is MFA, I then make another request to the `/api/v1/auth/factors/{ID}/verify` endpoint. This is successful and I get a session token.
- finally, try to get an access token for a given app by making a get request to `/api/v1/authorize`

```py
resp = requests.get("my-okta-url/api/v1/authorize", params=payload)
```

I get

```
resp <Response [405]>

 'errorLink': 'E0000022',
 'errorSummary': 'The endpoint does not support the provided HTTP method'
```

Comment: You may not have the implicit flow enabled, as I understand this is required for GET

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my organization does not acquired the feature from OKTA that allows to perform authentication through API.

I got this message when following the responses:
`The requested feature is not enabled in this environment`